# Debugging window.load(). Event not firing, no js or php errors output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having problems getting the window.load() event to fire on [this site](http://syrp.co.nz/wordpress/).

The problem occurred last night and no js or php errors are being output.
Which is making it particularly difficult to pinpoint the problem.

If you take a look at the file syrp.home.main.js, you'll see all sections within the homepage are initialised one by one. I've tried going through and commenting out each, however this didn't lend any insight to the problem.

I've looked at the JS Profiler in Chrome Dev tools but i haven't been able to narrow it down to a memory leak or infinite loop within a function yet. This could be because i'm not familiar enough with the JS Profiler.

Any tips as to what to look at next would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Cam

Comment: "The problem occurred ... " what changed?

Comment: there is an error in you script rather firebug is not opening in you website

Comment: @Pointy - i did put a couple of js files through http://jsbeautifier.org/ . but reverted them back, after i became aware of the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Located the problem, a coool 6 hours later.

I had declared my function that window.load() called as a var.

```
GLOBAL.els.$WINDOW.load(onPageLoad);

var onPageLoad = function(){};
```

changing it back to;

```
GLOBAL.els.$WINDOW.load(onPageLoad);

function onPageLoad(){};
```

note to self, 
never do that again.